# How to make the Contents display in the GO TO window?

Tags: kindle, table-of-contents

This is my table of contents:

```
  <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>

  <h2><a name="TOC">Contents</a></h2>
  <div class="center">
    <p class="no-indent"><a href=#item-1><em>Title Page</em></a></p>
    <p class="no-indent"><a href=#item-2><em>Copyright</em></a></p>
    <p class="no-indent"><a href=#item-3><em>Epigraph</em></a></p>
    <p class="no-indent"><a href=#item-4>Chapter 1</a></p>
```

And I have H2 tags in all the sections:

```
  <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>

  <h2 id="item-4">1.</h2>
```

It works but I doesn't show up in the GO TO window of my Kindle. This one:

[image]

This only happens when I use the official Amazon's Kindle converter. What should I do so my table of contents also shows in the GO TO window?